# why my class cannot be found in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, class

[image]

This error happens in `RegularLogin.swift`. I don't know why Xcode says use of undeclared type `TransmissionProtocol`
Here is my code in `TransmissionProtocol.swift`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var TransmissionProtocolConfiguration = [String: Int]()


public class TransmissionProtocol{

func setUpTransitPorotocol()
{
    /*------------client send to server---------------*/
    //first step
    TransmissionProtocolConfiguration["login"] = 1
    TransmissionProtocolConfiguration["register"] = 2


    /*------------sever send to client-----------------*/

    //login error
    TransmissionProtocolConfiguration["errLoginUsernameNotExist"] = -1
    TransmissionProtocolConfiguration["errLoginUsernameAlreadyOnline"] = -2
    TransmissionProtocolConfiguration["errLoginPassword"] = -3

    //register error
    TransmissionProtocolConfiguration["errRegisterUsernameExist"] = -4




}

}
```

Even though I add `NSObject`, it doesn't work:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using `@objc` or deriving from `NSObject`.

Comment: All of them belongs to the same target membership.

Comment: OK, if they're all part of the same target, then two other things to check: 1. Sometimes you can see spurious errors if there's something wrong in the code that precedes it (e.g. mismatched parentheses or braces ... I usually identify those sorts of issues by selecting all the code and pressing control-i to re-indent everything, at which point any mismatches stand out). 2. Less likely, there might be some problem with the project which can often be resolved by finding the derived data folder, quitting Xcode, emptying the derived data folder, and then re-opening the project and re-compiling.

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out?

Comment: Yes, already solved. I rewrote this part, using enumeration to declare it.